# Pulling Google Analytics data into SSRS reports

Tags: c#, reporting-services, google-analytics

How can I add Google Analytics as a Data Source to SSRS reports? I have already tried https://github.com/farzadpanahi/GoogleAnalyticsDataProcessingExtension but it gives errors when there was no data (empty data set) coming back from Google Analytics. Does anyone have a solution? It's really weird that there there doesn't exist a strong API from Google into SSRS.

Comment: Ever find a solution for this?  I created http://www.embeddedanalytics.com.  If you are trying to make basic charts it might meet your needs.  I had also considered making some sort of "connector" so that you could view Google Analytics data in Sql Tables.  Is there a big demand for this?